# What is the boundary conditions for infinite elastic isotropic medium in Navier's Equations?

Tags: waves, boundary-conditions, elasticity

Navier's equations of motion in seismic has 3 solutions, according to how it is resolved (boundary conditions):

- for P waves (compression waves)
- for S waves (shear waves)
- for Rayleigh (surface waves)

I know the boundary conditions for Rayleigh waves, that is the half-space (null stress at surface and null displacements and stress at infinite depth).

Which would be the boundary conditions for P and S waves? and why do they derivate for infinite medium and not half-space? What implies an infinite medium?

Answer (score 0):

The boundary conditions are given in terms of displacements and stresses, not in wave types modes. Here, you are mentioning two propagating (S and P) wave and one evanescent wave. In general, you need to superimpose them and impose the needed boundary conditions.

Notice that in the general case you can't even separate the waves in transverse and longitudinal polarization. That is only valid for infinite and semi-infinite media.

Regarding the boundary conditions in infinity for scatterers, you could have [Sommerfeld radiation condition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommerfeld_radiation_condition).